# SQL column sorting priority in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, select, group-by

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Products 
FROM Product p 
JOIN Category c ON (p.CategoryId=c.Id) GROUP BY c.id,c.name,p.CategoryId;

        ID NAME                           NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------
         1 LAPTOP                                          3
         2 TV                                              1


SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Products 
FROM Product p 
JOIN Category c ON (p.CategoryId=c.Id) GROUP BY c.name,c.id,p.categoryid;

        ID NAME                           NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------
         2 TV                                              1
         1 LAPTOP                                          3
```

Following query differs in the result because of the GROUP BY order. Could someone explain the reason for this difference?

Thanks!

Comment: These are different queries. The order in the group by is important

Comment: Yes, I know these are two different queries, but my question referred to the flipped query result, based on group by order. Nonetheless, I now know the reason for it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, as the RDBMS evaluates the query, it orders the rows in order to perform the `group by` efficiently, and then, due to a lack of an explicit `order by` clause, it emits the rows in that internal order.

But, you can never rely on this behavior.  If you care about a query returning rows in a particular order, you MUST specify that order using the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't supply an ORDER BY clause, then the GROUP BY ordering is generally the de-facto ordering of the query results (although this can vary by RDBMS; parallel query can cause the results to come out unordered).

If you want a specific ordering, then add an ORDER BY clause, e.g.

`SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Products 
FROM Product p 
JOIN Category c ON (p.CategoryId=c.Id) 
GROUP BY c.id,c.name,p.CategoryId
ORDER BY Number_of_Products DESC, name;`